# How to query latest documents first?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Flutter & Cloud Firestore. I have a collection. There are many documents in that collection. My question is how to fetch those documents on the time basis. Like I want to firstly show those documents data that I had added latest and the oldest documents data at the last. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have a `timestamp` field (named `addedAt` for example) in your documents, you can use the `orderBy` method `.orderBy('addedAt', descending: true)`

Comment: thnks you for the help